# using two type of permalinks WordPress for new posts

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, custom-wordpress-pages

i have WordPress website and i want to use different permalinks for it, the problem is i don't want to change Old posts permalink because  of SEO, i want to the old post don't change and the new posts with different permalink is there any way  to fix it?

Thanks.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems no way to do that, so i change default permalink to new one and i redirected old permalink urls to new one.
Thanks.